# Beamer: how to use \alert in itemize inside a block?

Tags: beamer, itemize, block

Edit 2017/08/23: Sorry, my first post wasn't compilable, here are MWE!

I'm having troubles using Beamer \alert in an itemize environment inside of a block environment...
I want to have a block inside of which I only put an itemize, and the content of each item has to be highlighted.
I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{My block}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \alert{Item1} (should be in red)
      \item \alert{Item2} (is in red)
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but the "Item1" appears as normal text in the output file.

I'm confused because it works perfectly if I add some text inside the block just before the itemize:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{My block}
    Some text
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \alert{Item1} (is in red)
      \item \alert{Item2} (is in red)
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or just before the first \alert

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{My block}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Some text \alert{Item1} (is in red)
      \item \alert{Item2} (is in red)
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or even if I put "almost nothing" (but still...) just before the first alert

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{My block}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \hspace{-3pt} \alert{Item1} (is in red)
      \item \alert{Item2} (is in red)
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the meantime, I just noticed that everything is fine if I don't use the Frankfurt theme (but of course I would like to use it...)

Does anyone have a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets compilable ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If I complete your first code fragment to a compilable example, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD1ws.png Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows us to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question! This is what I get compiling with pdflatex from texlive2017: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2lSa.png How are you compiling? Which tex distribution do you use? Same result for up-to-date xelatex and lualatex

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for you comment, I was using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3 ; I just updated my distribution (MiKTeX 2.9.6400, LaTeX2e <2017/04/15>) and everything is OK now!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by update

Comment: @Antonin Good to hear it's now working!